# Why are there 3 identical tables in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, stock, cataloginventory

We came across three absolutely identical in structure tables in M2 DB:

- `cataloginventory_stock_status`
- `cataloginventory_stock_status_idx`
- `cataloginventory_stock_status_tmp`

Anybody has any idea why such redundancy has been introduced?

Answer (score 7):

the `cataloginventory_stock_status` is the one that is used for reading in the frontend.
In order to not interfere with the table reads, when the stock index is running it is writing in the `_tmp` and/or `_idx` table and when it's done, the values are moved to the main table.

The temporary table used is determined by this method `\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\Stock\DefaultStock::tableStrategy::getUseIdxTable()`.
So in case it is `true`, the `_idx` table is used as temporary table. Otherwise the `_tmp` table is used.

The `_idx` table is used when you rebuild all the indexes, but I didn't find a case when the `_tmp` table is used, or what's the difference is between them.
I will report back when/if I find our more.

Comment: For tables with '_tmp' suffix MEMORY storage engine is used.

Comment: cataloginventory_stock_status & cataloginventory_stock_status_idx   which one is eligible for do some logic operations.  @Marius

Comment: `cataloginventory_stock_status`.