# What is the difference Between cataloginventory_stock_status & cataloginventory_stock_status_idx

Tags: table, stock-status, cataloginventory, magento1.9.2.3

If I use `cataloginventory_stock_status` and `cataloginventory_stock_status_idx` return different values, what is the main difference between these two tables?

Comment: Please check whether this link is useful for you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121427/why-are-there-3-identical-tables-in-magento2

Comment: @RajMohanR Got some stuff, thank you.